# Followup page results after scraping links not showing results (scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

After I scraped for the links, I got to the next page but scrapy is not showing the results expected. I think it might be a Xpath problem but when I use scrapy shell it seems to work just fine.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy

class TickersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tickers'
    allowed_domains = ['www.seekingalpha.com']
    start_urls = ['https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move']

    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a[contains(text(), "remarket gainers")]')
        for article in articles:
            link = article.xpath('.//@href').get()
        
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_ticker)
        
    def parse_ticker(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="bullets_ul"]/p[@class="bullets_li"]/span/a')
        for row in rows:    
            ticker = row.xpath('.//text()').get()
            date = response.xpath('.//*[@id="mc-hd"]/div[@class="mc-info"]/time/text()').get()
            yield {
                'ticker': ticker,
                'date': date
            }
```

I also tried to find the problem using `scrapy parse --spider=tickers -c parse_ticker https://seekingalpha.com/news/3594751-amd-swir-among-premarket-gainers` as a debuger and apparently it shows that is scraping something... still, nothing appears on when I run `scrapy crawl tickers`

By the way, the result should show the following strings on the terminal:

```
['NTZ', 'MGEN', 'THTX', 'MDGS', 'SWIR', 'PTE', 'ONCT', 'NAK', 'ABUS', 'GCI', 'TYME', 'SKX', 'AMD', 'SOGO', 'DPW', 'AIKI', 'TPH', 'MIST']
```

and the same date for each ticker (symbol):

```
Jul. 24, 2020 8:24 AM ET
```

This code should scrape only one link from the original page and then get a stock symbols list. (I'm still learning how to scroll down using scrapy-splash).

For consulting:
The 1st layer site: `https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move`
and the 2nd layer site: `https://seekingalpha.com/news/3594751-amd-swir-among-premarket-gainers`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule I always do a test run of the websites I want to scrape in scrapy. That means I use requests to make a simple HTTP get request. If i'm getting a status code error then it's easy to see, if I get the status code I want, I see if I can get the HTML I need.

### Information on Website

1. First url `https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move` requires headers to access the data, status code 403 when you do a simple HTTP request.
2. Second url h`ttps://seekingalpha.com/news/3594751-amd-swir-among-premarket-gainers` requires javascript. So if I get a status code from the requests package, the next step does it have the HTML I need? In this case it didn't. I then will proceed to disable javascript, and you can see in this case, despite how simple the page is, it is entirely javascript.

So those are the two challenges with the website. The first is easy to get around, you can grab the headers by navigating to the network tools of chrome or any other browser. Look for the document request and grab the headers.

The second challenge I was unable to find a useful HTTP request, so indeed using splash was needed.

### Code Example

#### settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'ticker'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ticker.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ticker.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'ticker.middlewares.TickerSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'ticker.middlewares.TickerDownloaderMiddleware':543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

Note that the site doesn't like being scraped so setting `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` is necessary

#### spider script

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TickersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tickers'
    allowed_domains = ['seekingalpha.com']
    start_urls = ['https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move']
    headers = {
    'authority': 'seekingalpha.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'user_id=47592629; user_nick=; user_devices=; u_voc=80; marketplace_author_slugs=; user_cookie_key=1twxdol; has_paid_subscription=false; user_perm=; user_limited=1; sapu=101; user_remember_token=d671e0cfe0c8cad02fc654861879b8caff2e9ebe; machine_cookie=8681468313726; portfolio_sort_type=a_z; _gcl_au=1.1.1589753539.1589100250; _ga=GA1.2.1230493623.1589100250; _pxvid=6b3d8782-929a-11ea-8553-0242ac12000a; ga_clientid=1230493623.1589100250; h_px=1; __gads=ID=be1eca3c9d406590:T=1589100255:S=ALNI_MaHwXVrMY7gtOlNqWPupPzHtynRgQ; _ig=57382e9c-bb0c-4f34-f294-f8f486e0fbfb; session_id=e0b9566d-469e-4a3a-ba12-b4e5e188b01c; gk_user_access=1**1595741665; gk_user_access_sign=88c34cce4bf29b2d8d7c4da10613017c277bf64f',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"801f62bb01abbf958120c0c6f48ca617"',
    }

    script = ''' 
        function main(splash, args)
            url = args.url
            assert(splash:go(url))
            assert(splash:wait(5))
            return splash:html()
        end

    '''

    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a[contains(text(), "remarket gainers")]')
        
        for article in articles:
            link = article.xpath('.//@href').get()
            new_link = response.urljoin(link)
           
            yield SplashRequest(url=new_link,dont_filter=True,callback=self.parse_ticker,endpoint="execute",
            args={'lua_source':self.script})
        
    def parse_ticker(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//*[@id="bullets_ul"]/p[@class="bullets_li"]/span/a')
        for row in rows:    
            ticker = row.xpath('.//text()').get()
            date = response.xpath('.//*[@id="mc-hd"]/div[@class="mc-info"]/time/text()').get()
            yield {
                'ticker': ticker,
                'date': date
            }
```

### Corrections to original code

1. Your `link` variable was only a relative link, so it was necessary to use `response.urljoin(link)` to get the link that scrapy would accept for `SplashRequest`. Indeed for `response.follow` it does accept relative links though.
2. Scrapy was filtering your HTTP requests so it was necessary in the request to have `dont_filter=True`.

### Explanation of Code Example

You can see at the top we have the headers from the original page so we can make a proper HTTP request to the first URL.

Using the `response.urljoin()` we can get the URL you require and to pass it to `SplashRequest`. SplashRequest requires a callback, endpoint, and we want to execute a custom script so defining that in the args parameters is necessary. We have included `dont_filter=True` in the request to stop scrapy from filtering the URL.

The callback is easy in this case. The endpoint by default in splash is render.html but setting this to `"execute"` allows us to execute custom scripts. The args parameters allows us to send any parameters we want. To direct splash to execute a script give the key `lua_source` the value of our custom script in this case `self.script`. Once the script is executed and returns the html in this case, the `parse_ticker` function can take the response and give you the desired outputs.

I will note that your variable articles only has one selector.

### Explanation of Custom Script

The main function is called by Splash and is the necessary function in our lua script, the main function receives splash as the object. This allows us to gain access browser function. We want to be able to pass arguments to direct splash to the url of choice. In the `SplashRequest` we define that url we want to use. To access that URL and tell splash to go to it we have the `splash.args` table whihc allows us to access that url. It has the original URL we specified in `SplashRequest` in it and we can access that through splash.args.url. So we define the variable `url = args.url`.

We direct splash to go to that url using `splash:go()` method which is easy to pickup. The `assert()` statement is similar to python and ensures that if there's a mistake in the URL then splash will not execute the script.

The `splash:wait()` function allows us to specify a wait time. I always tend to be slightly generous for loading times before grabbing the html.

The `splash:html()` function grabs the HTML that has been rendered by splash.

Every lua script should have an end to signify the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still have a couple of questions if you don't mind: 1. how do you know the website doesn't like to be scraped to make 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False' and 2. As standard should I always place your headers for every scrape? it seems that this headers it will be always better than the scrapy default one

Comment: When you run the script with Robotstext_obey=True you get this. [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://seekingalpha.com/robots.txt> (referer: None). It may at times actually say forbidden.

Comment: It's not really a question of the headers being better. The HTTP request did not work without some headers. The headers help you mimic the requests made of the server and to stop the server thinking you're a bot. I will admit I did not go through each line, it maybe that you just need say a useragent. I usually take the headers from a genuine load of the website i want to scrape and use that for the scrape.

Comment: I will also say that you will run into problems if you continuously scrape this site as you are having to set robotstxt_obey to false. They don't want you to take the data from seekingalpha.com/news.

Comment: I'm starting to understand what you can and can't do now. Thanks for the inputs

Comment: You're very welcome. Its useful to look at the scrapy log. Thats basically where I diagnosed most of your problems. I was getting 403 for both URLs you were trying to scrape. That how I knew there were problems that needed investigating.